# Issue with pressing Enter on the Date Time Picker component

Tags: javascript, accessibility, eonasdan-datetimepicker

So for the calendar icon on the date picker, I turned it into a button with class `datepickerbutton` and tried to navigate to it with the keyboard, pressing `enter` on the button.  When I did that, the arrow keys become not functional, as opposed to when you use the down arrow where it works fine.  I found a piece of the code that looks like it is the initial cause of the issue but can't figure out how it works or how to fix it.  If someone could help me figure out this part I could probably make a pull request to the repo with a fix.

Starting around line 1276 of: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js

```
for (index2 = keyBindKeys.length - 2; index2 >= 0; index2--) {
     if (!(keyMap[keyBindKeys[index2]] in pressedModifiers)) {
         allModifiersPressed = false;
         break;
     }
 }
```

UPDATE: I found that the cause of this is the tab key, when tabbing to the button it increases the keys pressed array, not sure why yet, still looking

Comment: When I try to add in console logs, and press enter, and try to navigate with arrow keys, this for loop and if statement become active but I don't know what the variables mean or what they are supposed to prevent, there are no comments here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue! it was caused by tabbing not being handled and when it was handled it would prevent it's default actions.  So i had to create a blank tab handler, then in the line where it says `if (handler)` I put an if so if it's the tab key it just sets the keystate object to empty otherwise it functions normally.